# AutoFixture and the Create method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fixtures, autofixture

I'm using AutoFixture for few weeks now and I wonder whether it's better to use a new Fixture for each object I want to create or I can just reuse the fixture I customized?

Here are few different approaches.

**Reuse the same fixture.**

```
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

ActionExecutedContext context = fixture.Customize(new CustomActionResult<RedirectResult>("Controller/Action"))
                                       .Customize(new CustomController())
                                       .Customize(new CustomActionExecutedContext())
                                       .Create<ActionExecutedContext>();

ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute attribute = fixture.Create<ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute>();
```

**Create a new fixture per object.** (Not sure whether it make sense because I see no reason to do that.)

```
ActionExecutedContext context = new Fixture().Customize(new CustomActionResult<RedirectResult>("Controller/Action"))
                                                             .Customize(new CustomController())
                                                             .Customize(new CustomActionExecutedContext())
                                                             .Create<ActionExecutedContext>();

ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute attribute = new Fixture().Create<ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute>();
```

**Create the SUT with the new keyword.**

```
ActionExecutedContext context = new Fixture().Customize(new CustomActionResult<RedirectResult>("Controller/Action"))
                                                             .Customize(new CustomController())
                                                             .Customize(new CustomActionExecutedContext())
                                                             .Create<ActionExecutedContext>();

ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute attribute = new ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute();
```

**Here is the complete test.**

```
[Fact]
public void Should_not_set_the_temp_data_when_the_model_is_valid()
{
    // Arrange
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

    ActionExecutedContext context = fixture.Customize(new CustomActionResult<RedirectResult>("Controller/Action"))
                                           .Customize(new CustomController())
                                           .Customize(new CustomActionExecutedContext())
                                           .Create<ActionExecutedContext>();

    ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute attribute = new ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute();

    // Act
    attribute.OnActionExecuted(context);

    // Assert
    context.Controller.TempData.Should().HaveCount(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *idiomatic* usage of AutoFixture is to use a shared instance of the `Fixture` class per test method.

So, while all the examples are technically correct, the last one tends to be more idiomatic as it doesn't use any shared state.

---

In fact, you can take advantage of the [AutoFixture.Xunit](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/) glue library:

```
PM> Install-Package AutoFixture.Xunit
```

Although I haven't tried to compile this, the example test could be rewritten as:

```
[Theory, TestConventions]
public void Should_not_set_the_temp_data_when_the_model_is_valid(
    ActionExecutedContext context,
    ExportModelStateToTempDataAttribute attribute)
{
    attribute.OnActionExecuted(context);
    context.Controller.TempData.Should().HaveCount(0);
}
```

Where `TestConventions` is defined as:

```
internal class TestConventionsAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal TestConventionsAttribute() 
        : base(
            new Fixture()
                .Customize(new CustomActionResult<RedirectResult>(
                               "Controller/Action"))
                .Customize(new CustomController())
                .Customize(new CustomActionExecutedContext()))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! yeah, I thought so. I'm already using the AutoDataAttribute for various things but I like to declare most of the things inside the test method. :)